# Creating bridge table in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to create to link two tables together with a bridge table in MariaDB. The table itself is called 'ActsIn' and is between the 'Actors' and 'Movies' tables.

In my ER diagram, the 'ActsIn' table consists of 3 attributes-

1. The Primary Key for the 'ActsIn' table which is a composite primary key made up of the two foreign keys below.
2. ActorName (A foreign key referencing the primary key in the 'Actors' table)
3. Title (A foreign key referencing the primary key in the 'Movies' table)

When I'm creating this table in MariaDB, do I treat the composite primary key as an attribute in its own right named ActorName/Title?

```
//Create table ActsIn
//
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ActsIn (
ActorName/Title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
ActorName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
Title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ActorName/Title)
);
```

Or make the 2 attribute fields ActorName and Title and then create a primary key referencing both of these attributes?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ActsIn (
ActorName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
Title VARCHAR(255),
PRIMARY KEY (ActorName, Title)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would normally have a table of actors (actor_id*, name), a table of movies (movie_id*, title), and a table relating one to the other (actor_id*,movie_id*) - `* = (component of) PRIMARY KEY`

If an actor can appear as several characters within the same movie, then you may want amend this model slightly.

Comment: Hi, the database I am building is in regards to the Marvel Cinematic Universe (a series) so is a bit more specific than a table of actors and general standalone movies, in the sense that so far the actors in this series have always played the same character. (But I appreciate the caution)

So it would be more effective to have the bridge table link an actor id and a movie id rather than the actor name to a movie name? (since the characters stay the same actors but appear in different movie titles)

Comment: @Goselnator - use the ids, not the names.  Especially if there are two different actors or movies with the same name.  And you might need a secondary `INDEX(movie_id, actor_id)` for `JOINing` the other direction.